# why the height is not set by javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to make the blocks in the row at the same height and take the height of the longest block. how can i do this because my code is not working.

i would like to select the blocks in loop not by selecting one by one by id but i cant do it.

i will write down the html and css and js code below.

nb: there will be more than one row in the project.

```js
/* global document */
var b_1 = document.getElementById("block_1"),
  b_2 = document.getElementById("block_2"),
  b_3 = document.getElementById("block_3");

function equalHeight() {
  var b1h = b_1.offsetHeight,
    b2h = b_2.offsetHeight,
    b3h = b_3.offsetHeight;

  if (b1h > b2h && b1h > b3h) {
    b_2.style.height = b1h;
    b_3.style.height = b1h;
  } else if (b2h > b1h && b2h > b3h) {
    b_1.style.height = b2h;
    b_3.style.height = b2h;
  } else if (b3h > b1h && b3h > b2h) {
    b_2.style.height = b3h;
    b_1.style.height = b3h;
  }
};
```

```css
.block {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #056c7c;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
}

.blocks {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container blocks">

  <div id="row_1">
    <div class="block" id="block_1">
      <h2>Block 1</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="block" id="block_2">
      <h2>Block 2</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="block" id="block_3">
      <h2>Block 3</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because the style node is not available. If you are going with script implementation, you can either go with `document.ready` of `jQuery`. I have done this by using pure `javascript`. Moved the script tag to bottom of body, this makes the script to execute only when the `DOM` is ready. Also append 'px' with the numeric value of style

```css
.block {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #056c7c;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
}

.blocks {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container blocks">
        <div id="row_1">
            <div class="block" id="block_1">
            <h2>Block 1</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
            </div>
        
            <div class="block" id="block_2">
            <h2>Block 2</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            </div>
        
            <div class="block" id="block_3">
            <h2>Block 3</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function equalHeight() {
        var b_1 = document.getElementById("block_1"),
        b_2 = document.getElementById("block_2"),
        b_3 = document.getElementById("block_3");
        var b1h = b_1.offsetHeight,
        b2h = b_2.offsetHeight,
        b3h = b_3.offsetHeight;

    if (b1h > b2h && b1h > b3h) {
        b_2.style.height = b1h + 'px';
        b_3.style.height = b1h + 'px';
    } else if (b2h > b1h && b2h > b3h) {
        b_1.style.height = b2h + 'px';
        b_3.style.height = b2h + 'px';
    } else if (b3h > b1h && b3h > b2h) {
        b_2.style.height = b3h + 'px';
        b_1.style.height = b3h + 'px';
    }
    };
    equalHeight();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The script is not running. You need something to start the script like on document load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS Flexbox. Flexbox automatically makes the elements the same height (taking the tallest element).

So you could do like this in your styling (you don't need JS):

```
.row_1 {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: thanks it is working but i need to make it by javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use display: table-cell on your blocks, that will make all with the same height

```css
.block {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 2px solid #056c7c;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
}

.blocks {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container blocks">

  <div id="row_1">
    <div class="block" id="block_1">
      <h2>Block 1</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="block" id="block_2">
      <h2>Block 2</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="block" id="block_3">
      <h2>Block 3</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is executed before the DOM content is loaded. Hence there was no DOM content present to change the height. Run the script after DOM content loading. You can use the following event listener for the same.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // Repace your script here
});
```